# HTML file calls PHP which runs fine but tags the PHP file name on the HTML I want to open

Tags: php, html

I am new to PHP,

The follow HTML calls send_form_email.php

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
<p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="#4F4F4F"><strong>Subscribe to our 
News letter:&nbsp; </strong></font><input type="text" value="enter your email address"           onfocus="blank(this)" onblur="unblank(this)" name="email" size="20">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

the follow PHP code runs correctly:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "subscribe@myithost.net";
    $email_subject = "News Letter Opt In";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but the email adress submitted does not appear to be valid";
        echo "The error appears below<br /><br />";
        echo 'Please go back and fix the error<br /><br />';
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the email you submitted.');
    }
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "News Letter Opt in Member, see below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
<?php include 'index.html'; ?>
<?php
}
?>
```

But the problem i have is that it returns me to http://www.myithost.net/send_form_email.php not www.myithost.net/index.html

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need to redirect the user. Put something likethis at the end of your php file

```
header("Location: http://mydomain.com/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for the PHP:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email_to = "subscribe@myithost.net";
    $email_subject = "News Letter Opt In";

    function died($error) {
        echo "We are very sorry, but the email adress submitted does not appear to be valid";
        echo "The error appears below<br /><br />";
        echo 'Please go back and fix the error<br /><br />';
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['email'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the email you submitted.');
    }
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
        $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
        died($error_message);
    }

    $email_message = "News Letter Opt in Member, see below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
        $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
        return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    // create email headers
    $headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n".
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

    header("Location: http://www.example.com/index.html"); // <--- ADD ME
    exit(); // <--- ADD ME



}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace :

```
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    ?>
    <?php include 'index.html'; ?>
    <?php
}
?>
```

By :

```
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
    header("Location: http://mydomain.com/index.html");
}
?>
```

N.B : Make sure no chars are displayed BEFORE header() function call.

Comment: Hi there, thank you very much for the changes required, it all works fine now